# UFT-Compare Two files except date

Tags: hp-uft

Actually i want to compare two files(.html format). Currently i am using 'ReadAll' function of file system object (VB). First file is already saved one, second will get generated at runtime. But in new file there is a value which changes in every run. Now, i want to compare the file content except that changed value.

Comment: Show your xml file.

Comment: What is your current way of comparing?

Comment: How is the example you've given an xml file? Do you mean you just want to compare 2 strings or are these the 2 string values you're able to pull out of the xml files? It would be useful to see some code here.

Comment: @Chetan Anand - Still - please add examples of the files and also what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a [File Content Checkpoint](http://qtp.blogspot.co.il/2013/01/file-content-checkpoint.html) which allows you to compare just parts of the file (and use regular expressions if you want).